# Linear combination Calculus

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

[image]

Given the following diagram, where A is a parallellogram. Written $s=-u+2v$ and $v=\frac13s+\frac16t.$ Now I want to find $a,b,c$ and $d$ such that 
$$A=\{P \mid \vec{OP}=xu+yv \text{ where } x\in[a,b] \text{ and } y\in[c,d]\}. $$

I have tried different things but nothing works. I have used the linear combination and I get $$-\frac13xs+\frac13xt+\frac13ys+\frac16yt$$ which does not help.

Comment: Perhaps it would be benecial to figure out the specific $x$ and $y$ values you'd have for the vertices of $A$.

Comment: How can I figure out these values?

Comment: Please help someody?

Comment: From the picture it looks to me like the vertices of $A$ are at $v$, $u+v$, $2v$, and $u+2v$.

Comment: And how does it help? Please do help. If I could find out I would not have written for help here.

Comment: Looking at those vertices we see that the components in the $v$ direction seem start at $1$ and end at $2$.  What about in the $u$ direction?

Comment: in u direction 0 to 1?

Comment: $ \ $Yep.$ \  \ $

Comment: @Rose123 Is $P$ a point in $A$ or a vector in $A$?